# How to change all nested dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

Using the code here, how would I change the value of `stock` for all the products with `newstock`?

```
products = {
    "apple": {"price": 3.5, "stock": 134},
    "banana": {"price": 6.82, "stock": 52},
    "cake": {"price": 23, "stock": 5}
    }

newstock = input("Enter amount to set :")
```

I assume a for loop like this would work

```
for x in products:
    products []["stock"]=newstock
```

But I'm not sure what to put in the empty []

Comment: Loop over `products.values()` and assign to the `stock` entry of each dictionary.

Comment: You should also read the input as an integer. `int(input(...))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you want to do

```
products = {
    "apple": {"price": 3.5, "stock": 134},
    "banana": {"price": 6.82, "stock": 52},
    "cake": {"price": 23, "stock": 5}
    }

newstock = int(input("Enter amount to set :"))


for i in products.values():
    i['stock'] = newstock
```

values() is a method that access your dict values that being the other dicts.

You can access a dict value by naming it is key inside brackets. You can loop through the multiple values and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Change

```
products []["stock"]=newstock
```

to

```
products[x]["stock"]=newstock
```

`x` is the dictionary key, you need to index the dictionary with it.